# Deleted users in database making wordpress site slow

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

Recently I accidentally deleted some users from the wp_users table in phpmyadmin. I did not realize that this would make my site super slow (Im assuming because of broken links???). How can I make my site run at normal speed again (either bring back the deleted users or remove the links that I assume are trying to access the old users)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:
1. Contact your hosting company
2. If you have backup you can import it.
3. Delete cache with plugins like w3 total cache or any plugin like that
But, really I think deleting users with phpMyAdmin can't slow down your site.

Comment: It was a plugin that was doing something. Everything works now. Thanks

Comment: OH, OK,! Can you please say me which plugin was doing that? (I bet wordfence. They had issues with that).

Comment: It was plugin I coded that stores online users in a database.